# When you need to go through multiple complicated and very difficult steps to accomplish an action

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Please imagine to accomplish an official task you have to go through a very strict rules and processed and of course multiple complicated steps to perform that action. For example you want to see a CEO of a big company. First you have to meet a secretary of a middle manage and then write your request and wait while they post you an e-mail and then you have to be present at a middle manager's office and after awhile if they recognize that you need to meet the CEO, they will route you to his representative and if you were supposed to meet the CEO, his / her deputy will set a time i.e. one month later to be able to see the CEO.

Is there any idiom in English which can describe such a situation in which you have to go through many difficult steps and hard work to do something especially in American English?

I have found the following idiom, but I don't know if it is in common use or old-fashioned and of course it can be used to describe my intent:

> - [go through hoops](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-jump-through-hoops)

Comment: It's usually *jump* through hoops--it refers to circus acts like [this](https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-dangerous-trick-tiger-jumping-through-the-fire-2789448.jpg).

Comment: @StoneyB the link is broken. Meanwhile, you did not define whether it works or not!

Comment: Hmm .. it works for me. Anyway, it's an image of a circus tiger jumping through two flaming hoops! .. Yes, **jump through hoops** is a very common idiom.

Comment: +1 for StoneyBs' *jump through hoops*.  We would use it like "I had to jump through a lot of hoops to see the CEO."